# Pretty print JSON that's already encoded in PHP

Tags: php, laravel

I have a PHP array that I save to a TEXT column in MySQL and use `json_encode($array)` before it's saved to the database.

Now I'd like to pretty print it in a HTML page (Blade template in Laravel), now it displays as a long line of text.

I think I can save it as an array and then use `json_encode()` when displaying it in the Blade template. But I'm wondering if I can save it to the database with `json_encode()`, and the pretty display it in JSON format in the Blade template.

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Why wouldn't you be able to do both?

Comment: It's generally not a good idea to store a json encoded array to your database, usually better to create an additional table or more columns

Comment: What if you `json_decode` it from database value and print the resulting array?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton That is far from true. You can save a json string to the database with 0 negative implications depending on your project.

Comment: @Lulceltech Did I imply that it is _never_ a good idea? That's why I said "_generally_". There ARE negative implications for doing so in most cases, not all, of course there are edge cases. (Of course it depends on how the data is _used_)

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Except for his use case has no reason to state that. If you are purely storing the JSON(not processing it using SQL) then there's no negative implications.

Comment: @Lulceltech You say that without knowing what this data is, if it's ever used for any kind of searching, or how big the data is. You only know OP wants to display the information on the page, not even _how_ necessarily (in a loop in a table, or just as a multi line string). What if a few months down the line OP wants to be able to search by this data? Well they just made that a million times harder on themselves.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Data size does not matter, let's assume there's 300 json keys in it, you go ahead and fill out 300 columns every time. What the data is or how large it is doesn't matter. It's being used for DISPLAY purposes. Now had he said he needed to search it then yes you would be correct. That was no where stated in the question.

Comment: @Lulceltech Consider this: does storing these objects as serialized data offer OP a clear added value over storing it in a relational form? If no, it's probably not worth the hassle of making it much more difficult to update these columns in the future if needed, it's probably not worth the hassle of redoing the entire database structure if the data needs to be searchable later. Storing it in relational form also guarantees the data is usable independantly without relying on another technology, and makes it _faster_ to query if needed in the future.

Comment: @Lulceltech On top of that, storing a json value to a relational database goes against basic structure rules of RDBMS. Also, there may be a performance hit in very large data sets with serializing/deserializing. If OP truly needs to do this, they should use a real document database instead of trying to use a RDMBS as one. My personal experience has lead me to leave my original comment, I used to store things as json strings all the time, but I've had to recreate a lot of structures and parts of applications because of it, and I was trying to leave a _general_ comment to get the OP thinking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
json_encode($json, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Save it like that then display it with `<pre>` and `<code>`(if needed) tags wrapped around it..